# convert multiple array into string and concat them with comma

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have set of arrays in an array and i want to convert inside array and separate it with comma and also with double quote so that it should differentiate.

```
example:
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arr2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var arr3 = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
var arr4 = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40];

this should converted and out should be

array["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20","21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30","31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40"]
```

what i have done so far is

```
var converArr1 = String(arr1);
var converArr2 = String(arr2);
var converArr3 = String(arr3);
var converArr4 = String(arr4);

var finalString = converArr1.concat(converArr2);
finalString = finalString.concat(converArr3);
finalString = finalString.concat(converArr4);

this is not concating it with double qoute
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be an array of the 4 strings, or do you want the result to literally be the string: `array["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10","11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20","21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30","31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40"]`?

Comment: I want the result to be an array of the 4 strings

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: The requirement seems very odd. For what reason would you possibly want to convert the sub arrays in to strings? It makes them harder to work with. For that reason this seems to be an XY question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map from the array to the string representation of the array (surrounded by quotes), then join these string representations on the comma (`,`), then use a template literal to surround with the `array[]`.

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var arr2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var arr3 = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
var arr4 = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40];

let result = "";

result = `array[${[arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].map(arr => `"${String(arr)}"`).join(",")}]`;

console.log(result);
```

If you want the result to be an array of the 4 strings:

```js
    var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var arr2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var arr3 = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
    var arr4 = [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40];

    let result = "";

    result = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4].map(arr => String(arr));

    console.log(result);
```